# Object(...) is not a function after update npm packages

Tags: reactjs, typescript

After 4 hours of debugging I find out problem is in import of files.

When I import file by this way:

index.tsx

```
import {profileAction} from './model';
// import {profileAction} from './model/action'; // when I change import to this it works
and model/index.tsx looks

export * from './action';
export * from './action-type';
export * from './api';
export * from './state';
export * from './sagas';
```

and model/action.ts looks:

```
export const profileAction = {...}
```

then I ever get error like this:

```
index.tsx:66 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.tsx:66:1)
    at ./src/app/profile/component/profile-gallery-filter-form/index.tsx (index.tsx:94:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
```

i haven't a clue why my imports are broken. Since update react-router-dom all imports works fine.

I run my project by this

```
  "scripts": {
      "start-dev": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
```

Is necessary change some configuration in tsconfig?

My tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```